# AWS ElastiCache (Memcached) continually climbing connection count

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I have a Lambda function in AWS (.NET Core) created to sweep Parameter Store parameters from Simple Systems Management into Memcached for easy / fast access by my serverless application. Despite my configuration function using the 'using' syntax for the Memcached client (which I expected to mean the connection would be released from the cache once the work was done) the connection count is continually climbing. My function is triggered once every 60 seconds to sync the parameter values.

Here is what the connection count looks like.

[image]

Here is my prototype function code:

```
    public async Task<bool> LcsConfigurationSweeper(ILambdaContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Configuration Sweeper activated");
            ElastiCacheClusterConfig config = new ElastiCacheClusterConfig("*******", *******);

            using (var client = new MemcachedClient(config))
            {
                GetParametersByPathRequest getParametersByPathRequest = new GetParametersByPathRequest
                {
                    Recursive = true,
                    WithDecryption = true,
                    Path = "***"
                };

                var getParametersByPathResponse = await _systemsManagementClient.GetParametersByPathAsync(getParametersByPathRequest);
                foreach (var parameter in getParametersByPathResponse.Parameters)
                {
                    Object value; // Memcached value

                    if (client.TryGet(parameter.Name, out value))
                    {
                        if (value.ToString() != parameter.Value)
                        {
                            context.Logger.LogLine($"Configuration sweeper has detected {parameter.Name} has changed. Updating.");
                            if (client.Store(Enyim.Caching.Memcached.StoreMode.Replace, parameter.Name, parameter.Value))
                            {
                                context.Logger.LogLine($"Parameter {parameter.Name} updated in cache OK.");
                                return true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                context.Logger.LogLine($"Exception: Parameter {parameter.Name} unable to be updated in cache.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        if (client.Store(Enyim.Caching.Memcached.StoreMode.Set, parameter.Name, parameter.Value))
                        {
                            context.Logger.LogLine($"Parameter {parameter.Name} stored in cache OK.");
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            context.Logger.LogLine($"Exception: Parameter {parameter.Name} unable to be stored in cache.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Exception: {ex.ToString()}");
        }

        return false; 
    }
```

Comment: Do you properly dispose your clients?

Comment: My understanding of the using syntax is that if the object implements IDisposable (which it must for using) then the object is disposed of outside the using block. Do I need to specifically call client.Dispose() on this client?

Comment: No you don't need to call `Dispose`, you are already doing so...

Comment: Can you repro the issue in a local console app?

Comment: Hi mjwills, yes that's what I thought (that using was taking care of dispose). I haven't reproduced the error in a local context yet. I have only used memcached in the context of a managed service within ElastiCache.

Comment: Give it a try locally. Debugging will be much simpler locally.

Comment: Okay, will do - cheers! (If I find out the cause, I'll report back here)

Comment: My bad I assumed `MemcachedClient` was a wrapper around the real client